# Find x y relation from differential relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x,y$ are connected by the differential relation:

$$ x^{'2}+ \dfrac {y^{'2}} { \sin ^2 x } = \cos^2 x $$

where the primes indicated are with respect to $t$.How can we find $x,y$ as functions of $t$?.

EDIT 1:

How can we find a relation between $x,y?$

EDIT 2:

Can we not assume for substitution setting $m ,t $ as constants

$$ \frac{x'}{\cos x} = \cos m t ,\, \, y'= \sin x \cos x \sin mt $$ and proceed integration on?

Comment: The equation includes two unknown functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. So, you have two unknowns but only one equation. The problem is underdetermined. One equation is missing. For example, if the missing equation is $y(t)=$ a given function of $t$  ,then in theory, $x(t)$ can be expressed on the form of a Relationship with the given $y(t)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y$ be a constant. The equation reduces to $$x'=\pm\cos x\implies x=\pm\arctan(\sinh t)$$
upto a constant.

Narasimham suggests an even easier solution : make $x$ constant then $y=\pm t\sin x\cos x$. Here $y$ depends only on $t$ as $x$ is a constant.

Comment: and when $  x$ is a constant  $ =x_1$ , $ y = t \sin x_1 \cos x_1 ? $

Answer (score 0):

The equation includes two unknown functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ . So, you have two unknowns but only one equation. The problem is underdetermined. One equation is missing.

But it is possible to express $y(t)$ as a function of $x(t)$ :

$$y(t)=\pm \int \sqrt{\left( \cos^2(x(t))-(x'(t))^2\right)\sin^2(x(t))}\:dt$$

If the function $x(t)$ is known, then $y(t)$ can be computed.

If $x(t)$ is unknown, then one equation is missing in order to find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

Comment: Known this, sorry my error, actually wanted f( x,y ) = 0

Comment: I don't think that is is possible in general. it is possible if two equations are given, for example $x'=F(x,y)$ and $y'=G(x,y)$ Then the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{G(x,y)}{F(x,y)}$ leads to solutions on implicit form $f(x,y)=0$ in some cases.

Comment: F,G  can be integrated if they are functions of either x or y...